# ¿Cómo creo un procedimiento para insertar datos?

Tags: c#, sql

actualmente intenté hacer un PROCEDURE para insertar datos a una DB, lo usaré en combinacion con C#, este es mi código:

```
CREATE PROC insertar_usuario
@nombres varchar(50),
@Login varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@Icono image,
@Nombre_de_icono varchar(max),
@Correo varchar(max),
@Rol varchar(max)
as
if exists (select Login FROM USUARIOS where Login=@Login and Nombre_de_icono=@Nombre_de_icono)
raiserror('Ya existe un usuario con ese nombre de usuario o icono, por favor ingrese de nuevo',16,1)
ELSE
insert into USUARIOS
values(@nombres,@Login,@Password,@Icono,@Nombre_de_icono,@Correo,@Rol)
```

El problema es que cuando lo trato de ejecutar me sale este error:

> Mens 257, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Procedimiento insertar_usuario, Línea 13
>   No se permite la conversión implícita del tipo de datos varchar a
>   varbinary. Utilice la función CONVERT para ejecutar esta consulta.

¿Cómo puedo corregirlo para que el PROCEDURE funcione correctamente? Gracias.

Observacion: Todas las tablas estan configuradas exactamente como fueron declaradas al inicio del codigo SQL.

Comment: cual es la linea 13? se ve que la tabla no esta configurada asi...

Comment: Después de leer mucho y buscar informacion finalmente cai en cuenta que mi SQL Manager tenia una opcion que no me permitia sobreescribir configuraciones o datos de tablas que estan siendo usados en ese momento. Deshabilite eso y ya pude hacerlo funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que veo es que no defines los nombres de los campos de la tabla cuando defines el `INSERT`

Sino los defines explicitamente aplicara el orden en que fueron definidos y puedeo que esto no coincida con los parametros que indicas

```
INSERT INTO USUARIOS (nombres, login, password, icono, nombreicono, correo, rol)
VALUES(@nombres,@Login,@Password,@Icono,@Nombre_de_icono,@Correo,@Rol)
```

indica el nombre de las columnas para asegurarte que coinciden con cada parametro en el orden correcto

Nota: puse los nombre de las columnas a modo de ejemplo, deberias cambiarlas por las que defines en tu tabla

Comment: Esto seria un problema si no tuviera todos los campos :/